# Show selected paint color on Button

Tags: android, button, background, styles

In my app I have a button, which changes the color when clicked. I want this button to show the selected paint color as its background color. This works somehow, but as the button is bigger than the viewable button element, it looks pretty bad and edgie. The color should only appear as a little square inside the button.

Is there a smart way to solve this problem? I've tried to use padding, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can give margin first and then put some padding. 
eg:

```
<Button 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="#f7d52e"/>
```

[image]

It will look like this, clickable area is yellow area, and button is till white area.

Comment: Unfortunately, that also doesn't work with my code. The button is just in the wrong place. Furthermore, I want to change the color on button click. It shouldn't be setted in the layout.

Comment: change background color of button can be done in code also. Can you paste your code here so I can check.

Comment: I have solved the problem with a little workaround: I use a small Button on top of the color_button. That works fine for me.